# Android throwing null pointer exception when accessing a keyboard from another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, keyboard

So I have a Fragment Activity that uses another fragments keyboard to add a marker to a map and I kep getting a null pointer exception. I'm also accessing the keyboard in its host fragment to add data to a list.To be clear the keyboard is being used by two fragments at the same time.
My code(This is the fragment where i access the keyboard from another fragment):

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            final EditText textLat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
            final EditText textLong = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
            EditText PO = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.POdata);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   /*this line throws the error*/PO.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        int Latitudei = Integer.parseInt(textLat.getText().toString());
                        int Logitudei = Integer.parseInt(textLong.getText().toString());
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Latitudei, Logitudei)));
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

this is keyboard's fragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            final EditText PO = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.POdata);
            EditText textLat = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textLat);
            EditText textLong = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textLong);
            ListView data = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    POin);
            data.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            PO.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        POin.add(PO.getText().toString());
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.adrian.xxxxxxxxxx.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:31)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Before you use findViewById you have to call setContentView() in activity onCreate().

Comment: ________________________________________________________

Comment: i have talking about first one.

Comment: @AdamPraiswater `getActivity()` returns null. You need to wait till the fragment is attached. Initialize view in onActivityCreated. By the way are you accessing views of one fragment in another??

Comment: but now the code isnt doing what its supposed to :/ @Haresh

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i am

Comment: @AdamPraiswater i suggest you read about fragments from the docs before going any further

Comment: @Raghunandan could you please provide an answer that more constructive other than telling me to read the docs

Comment: @Raghunandan otherwise i wouldnt have asked a question on StackOverflow in the first place.

Comment: @AdamPraiswater that is because you need to understand about fragments then you will know what you are trying to do is wrong

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer exception on a line of the form A.B.C means that something on the left-hand side of a dot is null. In this example :

either A is null;

or A.B is null.

There can be no other reason. So, as textView.getText() never returns null, the only possibility is that user is null.